# Entity Framework Core set Navigation property to null with include doesn't work

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to reset the project navigation property in my asset entity.

Asset Model (removed everything unrelated):

```
public class Asset
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ProjectId { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

Reset logic:

```
var asset = await context.Assets.Include("Project").FirstAsync(a => a.Id == assetId);
asset.Project = null;
asset.ProjectId = null;
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I included the project in the query and tried to set the Project and the ProjectId to null, but it doesn't update in the database. Additionally I already tried to only set the Project and only set the ProjectId to null but neither works.

There are a few related questions on SO for this problem, but for all of them the Include("xy") seems to solve the problem.

Comment: could you paste what error you get?

Comment: Is `ProjectId` the primary key? If so I don't think you can set it to `null`.

Comment: I don't get any exceptions. That's the funny part. It runs through but doesn't do it.
I already surrounded the call directly with a try catch to make sure the exception doesn't get swallowed somehow.

I added the asset model to the question to clarify. ProjectId is a nullable foreign key.

Comment: Virtual is only need if I want lazy loading with Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies, but I don't want lazy loading. With .Include("xy") it eager loads the navigation property as far as I know.

Comment: @madreflection Lazy loading has nothing to do with OP issue.

Comment: @Unavi Does `asset.Project` have value before setting it to `null`? Also does `asset.ProjectId` have value at that time? Anyway, the code should work even w/o `Include`. Are you sure you haven't configured the relationship / FK as required?

Comment: Yes and I found the problem. I set context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking; at some point in the context lifetime. Funny how those things always come up after I ask a SO question and not in the hours searching for the problem before xD

Comment: @Unavi Actually this can easily be overlooked - looking at the code one automatically assumes the first line returns tracked entity. I would suggest posting a short self answer - it could be very useful. Happy coding!

Comment: On it :) Thanks for bouncing some ideas back and forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy to solve but hard to track down. I called context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking; on the context at some point before, which makes the result read only. [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking)

Two solutions:

- Either remove this line (for me it was a leftover from playing around),
- or add .AsTracking() to the query if you want to keep the general no tracking behavior.

With my example from above it would look like:

```
var asset = await context.Assets.Where(a => a.Id == assetId).Include("Project")
                                .AsTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync()
asset.Project = null;
```

If you have the foreign key available on your model you can remove the include and just set the foreign key to null like this:

```
var asset = await context.Assets.Where(a => a.Id == assetId).AsTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync()
asset.ProjectId = null;
```

And again without context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking; you can omit .AsTracking() because that is the standard behavior.